# Correct way to define types of optional container-type arguments in MyPy

Tags: python, mypy, static-typing

The convention for optional container-type arguments in Python is the following:

```
def f(lst=None):
   if lst is None:
      lst = []
   ...
```

I have this pattern quite a bit over my code to avoid issues with lists, or dictionaries or anything being defined globally for the function, and having problem if something downstream mutates that global object.

This works well, but now I am adding static type checks to certain parts of my code and I am wondering what could be the best way to add them here. `lst` must have the type `Optional[List[T]]` when defined as a keyword argument, but after the initial check it should have `List[T]` as a type. I can't redefine the type of `lst` after its declaration, and creating a new argument seems to add unnecessary lines of code and prone to confusion. What would be the best way to type-check this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. Apparently, mypy is smart enough to understand the switch you're doing from `Optional` to `List`. See this code:

from typing import Union, Optional, List

```
def bar(lst: List):
    print("Bar")
    print(lst)

def foo(lst:Optional[List] = None):
    if lst is None:    # Removing these two lines
        lst = []       # results in a type mismatch error
    print(lst)
    bar(lst)           # this is okay. mypy understands that lst is a 'List' 

foo([1, 2, "x"])      # Okay 
foo(None)             # okay
foo("some string")    # error, of course
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. It gave me an error in a function where I wasn't exactly doing 'if X is None', but instead I was doing an extra check before and the code was 'elif X is None'. A minor change in that code and MyPy recognizes it perfectly, thank you very much!